# How to do row_number partition by in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a Sql like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY bpid ORDER BY LoginTime DESC) rn, userid
   FROM xxx_table) t
WHERE rn <= 3
```

How to do this in mongodb? I write query like this:

```
{$sort:{"LatestLoginTime":-1}},
{"$limit":2000},
{
    $group:{
        _id:"$BPID",
        items:{
            $push:{
                userId:'$UserID',
                date:'$LatestLoginTime'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example document?

Comment: the document columns are :

BPID,UserID,LatestLoginTime

Comment: Did u get solution for this

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

$last
Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the last document in a group of documents that share the same group by a field. Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order.

Check first example